# algorithm to check if a space is convex

Tags: algorithm

is this possible to do in less than polynomial time?

Comment: What sort of space?  Over what range?  First derivative isn't sufficient?

Comment: Polynomial of what? Number of points defining the space?

Comment: I think he is meaning metric space, so how you will do it with derivative?

Comment: Do you mean check if a polygon is convex?

Comment: @GregRogers: I assumed that's what he's talking about; whether or not a volume (presumably defined by a polygon) is convex.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Hmm... interesting question.  I believe the answer is yes.  Roughly, find the plane equation of each of the faces; for every pair of conjoined faces, if the angle between them is obtuse, the volume is concave.  This should run in O(log(n)) time.

I'd bet there's some way of working this out using a graph-coloring algorithm, but I'm just not that clever...

Comment: @Yogi: what?  finding the plane equation for each face is O(1); it's O(log(n)) because of comparing pairs of conjoined planes.  Remember, finding the plane equation for a polygon is constant time, therefore it's O(1), therefore it doesn't affect the overall order of the algorithm.

Answer (score 4):

Use more words.

We can;t know what exactly you are asking.  We can only guess.

I don't think spaces could be convex or concave in general... maybe you mean volume or area?  In any case I dont think you are going to beat polynomial time, given the complexity of the surface is going to be polynomial in nature.